# How to get access to entire subdocument(array of objects within array of objects) using moongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**my Schema :**

```
var schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    classes:[
      {
       c_name:String,
       c_strn:String,
       students:[
       {s_name:String,
        s_roll:String,
        s_address:String
       }
       ]
      }
    ],
});
var school = mongoose.model('school',schoolSchema);
```

**Sample Doc :**

```
var sainik = new school({name:'sain',
                         classes:
                         [
                          {
                          c_name:'1(one)',
                          c_strn:'100',
                          students:[
                            {
                              s_name:"Leo",
                              s_roll:"17",
                              s_address:"strt24",
                            },
                            {
                              s_name:"Kyle",
                              s_roll:"18",
                              s_address:"strt24",
                            }
                          ]//array of students
                          }
                         ]//array of classes
                        });
sainik.save().then(()=>console.log("Save it"));
```

**Code :**

```
app.get('/home/:id/:cid',function(req, res){
school.find().exec(function(err,data){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log(data);
    res.render("classDet",{data:data});
  }
})
});
```

Here i need to know how to get access to the individual classes using the class id and to print the array of students as list in the "classDet"
Basically I am creating a school management system in which there will be many classes and inside that classes will be list of students.
I want to print all the students in each classes only when the parent class is access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either one of these :

```
app.get('/home/:id/:cid', function (req, res) {
    school.find({ id: id, 'classes.c_id': cid }, { _id: 0, 'classes.c_id.$.students': 1 }).lean().exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
            res.render("classDet", { data: data });
        }
    })
})
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0c_cMA9qaaJ)

```
app.get('/home/:id/:cid', function (req, res) {
    school.aggregate([{ $match: { id: id } }, { $unwind: '$classes' }, { $match: { 'classes.c_id': cid } }, { $project: { _id: 0, students: '$classes.students' } }]).exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
            res.render("classDet", { data: data });
        }
    })
})
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gecNUutCdyf)

**Note :** There will be a slight difference in both results, you can test it & choose one out of those, Also keep in mind if in case `id` from request is being searched against `_id` in DB then you need to convert `id` string to `ObjectId()` before using it in queries. Also we're using `.lean()` in `.find()` to convert mongoose docs into Js objects in order to access keys in data while working on it in code.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked!!!. I am getting an output of [ { classes: [ [Object] ] } ] . can you tell me how to loop in this data particulary the students array in ejs

Comment: @BestOFBest : Try that aggregate query which better for your needs..